# does text to speech not work on the emulator?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

in the app I am developing I would like add support for TTS using `android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech`. It works fine on physical device, but in the emulator instead of speak this log appears on logcat

```
2021-07-08 09:39:32.947 5251-5360/com.google.android.tts E/native: android_asset_file_resource.cc:131 Failed to obtain asset "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.tts/app_voices_greco_v2/it-it-x-kda/hmm/roman_numeral_android.far"!
2021-07-08 09:39:32.947 5251-5360/com.google.android.tts E/native: data_source.cc:72 Failed to open data resource from "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.tts/app_voices_greco_v2/it-it-x-kda/hmm/roman_numeral_android.far"
2021-07-08 09:39:32.947 5251-5360/com.google.android.tts E/native: pipeline_builder.cc:77 Failed to load resource: name: "classify_roman_numerals_grm_fst" classname: "GrmManager" params { [speech.tts.GrmFarResourceParams.id] { fst_names: "ROMAN_NUMERAL" fst_names: "MORPHOSYNTACTIC_FEATURES" data_source { path: "roman_numeral_android.far" type: FILE } } }, status=*** Error status -79202: Failed to parse GRM data source ***
2021-07-08 09:39:32.947 5251-5360/com.google.android.tts E/native: local_pipeline_runner.cc:89 Greco internal error: *** Error status -79202: Failed to parse GRM data source ***
2021-07-08 09:39:32.947 5251-5360/com.google.android.tts E/native: tts_controller.cc:121 Failed to load resources!
2021-07-08 09:39:32.947 5251-5360/com.google.android.tts E/native: tts_controller_jni.cc:182 Failed to initialize controller!
2021-07-08 09:39:32.947 5251-5360/com.google.android.tts E/AndroidTtsController-tts: Failed to load pipeline definitions!
2021-07-08 09:39:32.947 5251-5360/com.google.android.tts E/ControllerSynthesizer: Failed to load synthesis data.
2021-07-08 09:39:32.947 5251-5360/com.google.android.tts E/LocalSynthesizer: Failed initializing controller with voice it-it-x-kda
2021-07-08 09:39:32.947 5251-5360/com.google.android.tts E/LocalSynthesizer: Synthesis request for unsupported locale: ita-ita
```

even from settings.
It is an API 25 emulator, just created.

Comment: Check the locales available on the android default TTS engine matches those.

Comment: `2021-07-08 09:39:32.947 5251-5360/com.google.android.tts E/LocalSynthesizer: Synthesis request for unsupported locale: ita-ita` - Shouldn't the locale be **`it-IT`**?

Comment: why not? I am developing an application in Italian

Comment: I think that's the cause of the error. **`ita-ita`** is not a valid locale, as the error says.

Comment: Im my code I do
```tl = TextToSpeech(applicationContext) { status ->if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) tl.language = Locale.ITALIAN
```
so I have no control on it.
In the physical device works, but I need to do a presentation by videoconference